# app got crashed when notification comes on background using xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am using xamarin.forms for my android project. When I upgrade the code on android API level 33 mobile on foreground, notification comes fine.
When app is on background, I got the following issue:
Error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: com.fd.trucker.app: Targeting S+
> (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or
> FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent.

```
My code:
public void SendNotifications()
        {
            try
            {
                NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager)GetSystemService(NotificationService);
                var seed = Convert.ToInt32(Regex.Match(Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), @"\d+").Value);
                int id = new Random(seed).Next(000000000, 999999999);
                var push = new Intent();
                var fullScreenPendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(this, 0, push, PendingIntentFlags.Immutable);
                NotificationCompat.Builder notification;
                if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.O)
                {
                    var chan1 = new NotificationChannel(PRIMARY_CHANNEL, new Java.Lang.String("Primary"), NotificationImportance.High);
                    manager.CreateNotificationChannel(chan1);
                    notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, PRIMARY_CHANNEL);
                }
                else
                {
                    notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, PRIMARY_CHANNEL);
                }
                    notification.SetContentIntent(fullScreenPendingIntent)
                         .SetContentTitle("Destination Arrival")
                         .SetContentText("It appears you've arrivedDestroy at the destination.Please enter the BL & Scale Ticket.")
                         .SetLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(Resources, Resource.Drawable.icon))
                         .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.icon_transparent)
                         .SetStyle((new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()))
                         .SetPriority(NotificationCompat.PriorityHigh)
                         .SetColor(0x0a384a)
                         .SetAutoCancel(true);
                    manager.Notify(id, notification.Build());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Logger.GetInstance().LogCreate("Droid/MainActivity/SendNotifications/Exceptionn: " + ex.Message);
                AppCenterDataProvider.GetInstance().TrackError("Droid/MainActivity/SendNotifications/Exception", "", ex);
            }
        }
```

Please give me solution for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can recheck your problem by following steps as follows:

1.try to update all your libraries and nugets to the latest;

2.recheck if you have installed the latest nuget [Xamarin.AndroidX.work.runtime](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.AndroidX.Work.Runtime/);

3.try to add `PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE` to your pending intents.

Here is an example :

```
    var intent = new Intent(this,typeof(MainActivity));

    var pendingIntentFlags = (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.S)
        ? PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent | PendingIntentFlags.Mutable
        : PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent;
    var pendingActivityIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(Application.Context, requestCode, intent, pendingIntentFlags);
```

For more information, you can check this link: [PendingIntent#FLAG_IMMUTABLE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent#FLAG_IMMUTABLE)